# click button to go different direction on the same page

Tags: html

How can i perform the button function when click it, it will go to another direction on the same page?  i know how to do in href but what if button ?

if a href i use this method 
`<a href="#BTM" name="Top">`
`<a href="#Top" name="BTM">`
what if button ?

```html
<input type="button" name="TOP" value="CLICK TO GO BOTTOM ">
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>

<input type="button" name="BTM" value="CLICK TO GO TOP ">
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try simply like this:

```
<html>

<input type="button" id="top"name="TOP" value="CLICK TO GO BOTTOM " onClick="document.getElementById('bottom').scrollIntoView();" >
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>

<input type="button" id="bottom" name="BTM" value="CLICK TO GO TOP " onClick="document.getElementById('top').scrollIntoView();" >
</html>
```